# Entity Framework and property mapping from another table

Tags: c#, c, entity-framework

I need to map a standard property (string) for a class which is not available in table mapped for class but in another table.

```
public class Centre
{
     public int ID;

     public string Name;

     public string DescriptionInfo;
}
```

Database contains two tables - one is Centre and another is InfoText.

With above case want to populate the Centre entity and filled the DescriptionInfo property from InfoText table.  InfoText table might have other column on which filter needs to be applied since this table contains description for other entities.

Options available are make a view of tables or use inheritance. Don't want to use inheritance OR create view for same.

Is it possible some other to make that join and fill the description.

Comment: How does the InfoText table link to the Centre table? If InfoTable has a CentreID field then if you set up a Foreign Key EF will map this relationship for you (assuming database first approach?)

Comment: InfoText table has centreID as foreign key and another column "Attribute" can has different values like 'intro', 'info'. Depending on filter attribute value string property needs to be filled.